# What kind of error is this? Trying to consume an API with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am practicing callbacks with an API (Rick and Morty API) and using XMLHttpResquest.

As you see, this is my code:

```
let XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
let API = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character';

function fetchData(url_api, callback) {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET', url_api, true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
        if(xhttp.readyState === 4) {
            if(xhttp.status === 200) {
                callback(null, JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText))
            } else {
                const error = new Error('Error ' + url_api);
                return callback(error, null);
            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.send();
}

fetchData(API, function(error1, data1) {
    if (error1) return console.error(error1);
    fetchData(API + data1.results[0].id, function(error2, data2) {
        if (error2) return console.error(error2);
        fetchData(data2.origin.url, function (error3, data3) {
            if (error3) return console.error(error3);
            console.log(data1.info.count);
            console.log(data2.name);
            console.log(data3.dimension);
        });
    });
});
```

It returns an error, but I'm not sure what type of error:

> yarn run v1.22.4 $ node src/callback/challenge.js Error: Error
>   https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character
>       at exports.XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (A:\Carrera de Backend con JavaScript\Curso de
>   Asincronismo\asincronismo\src\callback\challenge.js:12:31)
>       at exports.XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (A:\Carrera de Backend con JavaScript\Curso de
>   Asincronismo\asincronismo\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
>       at setState (A:\Carrera de Backend con JavaScript\Curso de Asincronismo\asincronismo\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
>       at exports.XMLHttpRequest.handleError (A:\Carrera de Backend con JavaScript\Curso de
>   Asincronismo\asincronismo\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:532:5)
>       at ClientRequest.errorHandler (A:\Carrera de Backend con JavaScript\Curso de
>   Asincronismo\asincronismo\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:459:14)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
>       at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) Done in 1.51s.

I understand that the if condition is not being met, but how can I solve it? Does not give me more details.

Comment: why not use `fetch` API? It's supported in most modern browsers. If not you can use libraries like `axios`

Comment: Because I am trying to practice callbacks. If I use fetch I will be forced to use promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the url. I forgot to put the / at the end. So when nesting the url with the rest of the request it did not recognize the string as a valid url.